# Divs expanding under other divs on hover with JS - IE8 :¬(

Tags: javascript, html, hover, jquery-animate

I'm struggling with some divs in IE8.
And unfortunately I'm stuck in IE8 due to my company's limitations - hell we're still on XP. But I digress.

I have an information panel of quick links which is 15 boxes in five rows of three.
Each row of three is in its own containing div.
On hovering over the boxes they expand to show the full contents of links.

My problem is that the top of the boxes expand within the containing div, thus truncating the text and the bottom expand UNDER the next rows.

I've tried playing with the z indices and different overflow settings but to no avail. I can't post a jsfiddle because it doesn't work in IE but my code is here if anyone can help..

Thanks for any help

Chris

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper
{    align: center;
margin-bottom:-10px;   }

#header
{    align: center;
width:100%;
margin-left:15px; }


#panelcontainer
{
float:right;
margin-right:-30px;
width:480px;
overflow:visible;
}

#catcontainer
{
float:right;
width:495px;    
}


.cat
{
background-color: #000000;
line-height: 1.7em;
float:right;
color:yellow;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 2px;
margin-left: 3px;
padding-left: 5px;
width:154px;
height:100px;
border: solid 1px; 
border-color: #ffff80;
overflow: hidden;
 }


.cat3g
{
position: absolute;
z-index: -100000;
overflow: visible;
}
```

**HTML (first two rows only)**

```
<body>

<title>Info Panel</title> 
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<center><img src="images/ttpip.png" border=0 height=45px></center>
</div>


<!-- The squares-->

<div id="catcontainer">
<div class="cat3g" style="top: 260px;">
<div class="cat">

    <strong>Heading 1</strong><br>
    <a href="link" target="_blank">Link 1</a><br> 
    <a href="link" target="_blank">Link 2</a><br> 

</div>

<div class="cat">

    <strong>Heading 2</strong><br>
    <a href="link" target="_blank">Link 1</a><br> 
    <a href="link" target="_blank">Link 2</a><br>
</div>


<div class="cat">

    <strong>Heading 3</strong><br>
    <a href="link" target="_blank">Link 1</a><br> 
    <a href="link" target="_blank">Link 2</a><br>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cat3g" style="top: 370px;">
<div class="cat">

    <strong>Heading 4</strong><br>
    <a href="link" target="_blank">Link 1</a><br> 
    <a href="link" target="_blank">Link 2</a><br> 

</div>

<div class="cat">

    <strong>Heading 5</strong><br>
    <a href="link" target="_blank">Link 1</a><br> 
    <a href="link" target="_blank">Link 2</a><br>
</div>


<div class="cat">

    <strong>Heading 6</strong><br>
    <a href="link" target="_blank">Link 1</a><br> 
    <a href="link" target="_blank">Link 2</a><br>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function()
{
    $('.cat').hover(function (e) 
    {    $(this).stop(true, true).animate(


{   marginTop: e.type == 'mouseenter' ?  "-50px" : '2px',
        height: e.type == 'mouseenter' ?  "220px" : '100px',
            fontSize: e.type == 'mouseenter' ?  "20pt" : '10pt'
    }
    , 400);

    });});

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm not sure entirely what your issue is. The js is running and performing what I would have expected it to do. So currently. if you hover over your top row the items get bigger and move up. If you hover over the middle and the bottom row it over laps the row above. Hovering over the middle right pushes the bottom to the left. Hovering over middle left moves the bottom down. Which one of these is the problem. Just so I understand properly

Comment: Hi Rob, I'm expecting the hovered box to expand over the top of the boxes in the rows above and below. Currently, the containing div `cat3g` is giving a "letterbox view" that's chopping off the top and bottom in an `overflow:hidden` kind of way. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the kind of thing you want, or if you can pick bits out to help with your formatting. But here's some html I've been playing with using relative and absolute positioning, also using the additional function for the hover in jquery, which enables you to define what to do on unhover. Plus the adding and removing of classes on an object.

Hope it helps

Styles

```
<style>
    .box {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        padding: 2px;
    }

    .boxContent {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .boxContainer {
        width: 312px;
        height: 500px;
    }

    .top {
        z-index: 9999999;
    }
</style>
```

body

```
<div class="boxContainer">
    <div class="box left">
        <div class="boxContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box middle">
        <div class="boxContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box right">
        <div class="boxContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box left">
        <div class="boxContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box middle">
        <div class="boxContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box right">
        <div class="boxContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box left">
        <div class="boxContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box middle">
        <div class="boxContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box right">
        <div class="boxContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box left">
        <div class="boxContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box middle">
        <div class="boxContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box right">
        <div class="boxContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box left">
        <div class="boxContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box middle">
        <div class="boxContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box right">
        <div class="boxContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function () {


        $('.middle .boxContent').hover(function (e) {

            $(this).addClass("top");
            $(this).stop(true, true).animate(
        {
            marginTop: "-50px",
            marginBottom: "-50px",
            marginLeft: "-50px",
            marginRight: "-50px"
            //marginTop: e.type == 'mouseenter' ? "-50px" : '0px',
            //marginBottom: e.type == 'mouseenter' ? "-50px" : '0px',
            //marginLeft: e.type == 'mouseenter' ? "-50px" : '0px',
            //marginRight: e.type == 'mouseenter' ? "-50px" : '0px',
            //fontSize: e.type == 'mouseenter' ? "20pt" : '10pt'
        }
            , 400);

        }, function () {


            $(this).stop(true, true).animate(


        {
            marginTop: "0px",
            marginBottom: "0px",
            marginLeft: "0px",
            marginRight: "0px"

        }, 400);
            $(this).removeClass("top");

        });


        $('.left .boxContent').hover(function (e) {

            $(this).addClass("top");
            $(this).stop(true, true).animate(
        {
            marginTop: "-50px",
            marginBottom: "-50px",
            marginRight: "-100px"
        }
            , 400);

        }, function () {


            $(this).stop(true, true).animate(


        {
            marginTop: "0px",
            marginBottom: "0px",
            marginLeft: "0px",
            marginRight: "0px"

        }, 400);
            $(this).removeClass("top");

        });


        $('.right .boxContent').hover(function (e) {

            $(this).addClass("top");
            $(this).stop(true, true).animate(
        {
            marginTop: "-50px",
            marginBottom: "-50px",
            marginLeft: "-100px"
        }
            , 400);

        }, function () {


            $(this).stop(true, true).animate(


        {
            marginTop: "0px",
            marginBottom: "0px",
            marginLeft: "0px",
            marginRight: "0px"

        }, 400);
            $(this).removeClass("top");

        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Rob, thanks! That's put me on the right track - however it doesn't work correctly in IE8. The addition of `left`, `middle` and `right` to `box` in the class statement is not recognized in the HTML. The boxes appear with no width, or height and on hover all move diagonally top left. I see you are referring to classes of `.left`, `.right` and `.middle` in the script - again is this a limitation of IE8?

Comment: Make sure you've added the doctype on your page. I've read that prevents ie8 recognising multiple classes if you don't have it :-)

Comment: That did the trick Rob many thanks! Plus some other fiddling. Just having a weird issue between versions of IE8 now - unbelievable! I have a version at 8.0.6 which works and I have 8.0.7 on another machine which is not behaving. All boxes open underneath each other (back to my original problem!) and the top left one is the only one that smoothly animates - the others just snap to the expanded size. It's almost like the `.top` class is being ignored.

Comment: Ok fixed now - <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8"> did the trick. I hate IE. Thanks for all your pointing in the right direction. I've learned a lot.

Comment: Hi again @Rob White - just noticed something with your script/html which I've incorporated. The boxes expand over the top of their neighbours ok, but when you hover out, the right hand edges flips UNDER the neighbouring square before contracting. The left hand side behaves as expected. Consequently the right column work great, the middle half does, the left not at all. Any clues? Moving `$(this).removeClass("top");` around makes no difference.